# How to make a simple auth in Python?

Tags: python, authentication

I'm trying to create an auth to retrieve information from an API. I create something like this:

```
def get_movies(self):
    """Get api data"""
    url = '{}/Get_Cinema_Filmes?AUTENTICACAO={"USUARIO":user,"SENHA":pass}'.format(self.url)
    return requests.get(url).json()
```

I know I can make something like `request.get(url, auth=...)`, but I don't know how to make in this case.

The problem here is this part `AUTENTICACAO={"USUARIO":user,"SENHA":password}`. I don't know how to pass the user and password parameters with this format.

Is there a way to do this using BasicAuth or even oAuth?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I made the auth this way. It works!

```
def get_movies(self):
    """Get api data

    """
    url  = '{}/Get_Cinema_Movies'.format(self.url)
    auth = '{"AUTH":{"USER":"user","PASS":"password"}}'

    return requests.post(url, data=auth).json()
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Basic Auth:

```
username = "fred"
password = "secret"
auth = (username, password)
return requests.get(url, auth=auth)
```

Comment: Yeah, already did that way. It didn't work.
As I said, my problem here is `AUTENTICACAO={"USUARIO":user,"SENHA":password}`, it won't recognize the `auth` because of this part.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then the host isn't using Basic Auth.  You'll have to follow whatever documentation they provide for performing authentication.